# java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters

Tags: database, ms-access

It seems that this part of my code is where the exception occurs:

```
c = dbConnection.getConnection(); 
q = "SELECT * FROM book WHERE nextInc<=? AND inlib=?";
s = c.prepareStatement(q); 
s.setBigDecimal(1,BigDecimal.valueOf(curDate.getTime())); 
s.setBoolean(2,false); 
rs = s.executeQuery(); <-- Error.
```

I'm using "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216425), the error could occur because of non-existent column.

Could you put the structure of the table here?

Comment: I feel like an idiot, I mistyped the column name. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

After checking all of my column names, I also discovered that double quotes around a string literal will cause the same error.

Wrong: `WHERE foo LIKE "bar"`

Right: `WHERE foo LIKE 'bar'`

Just an FYI for any non-Access folks scratching their heads (like me).