# java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 2

Tags: java, sql, swing, ms-access

This is my `javax.swing` class. But it always throws the error  `java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 2`. Not quite sure what is causing it. Where is the error?

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SwingSearchApp extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    //Initializing Components
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    JLabel lb, lb1, lb2, lb3, lb4, lb5;
    JTextField tf1, tf2, tf3, tf4, tf5;
    JButton btn;

    //Creating Constructor for initializing JFrame components
    SwingSearchApp() {
        //Providing Title
        super("Fetching Student Information");
        lb5 = new JLabel("Enter Name:");
        lb5.setBounds(20, 20, 100, 20);
        tf5 = new JTextField(20);
        tf5.setBounds(130, 20, 200, 20);
        btn = new JButton("Submit");
        btn.setBounds(50, 50, 100, 20);
        btn.addActionListener(this);
        lb = new JLabel("Fetching Search Information From Database");
        lb.setBounds(30, 80, 450, 30);
        lb.setForeground(Color.red);
        lb.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500, 500);
        lb1 = new JLabel("U_Name:");
        lb1.setBounds(20, 120, 100, 20);
        tf1 = new JTextField(50);
        tf1.setBounds(130, 120, 200, 20);
        lb2 = new JLabel("U_Mail:");
        lb2.setBounds(20, 150, 100, 20);
        tf2 = new JTextField(100);
        tf2.setBounds(130, 150, 200, 20);
        lb3 = new JLabel("U_Pass:");
        lb3.setBounds(20, 180, 100, 20);
        tf3 = new JTextField(50);
        tf3.setBounds(130, 180, 200, 20);
        lb4 = new JLabel("U_Country:");
        lb4.setBounds(20, 210, 100, 20);
        tf4 = new JTextField(50);
        tf4.setBounds(130, 210, 100, 20);
        setLayout(null);
        //Add components to the JFrame
        add(lb5);
        add(tf5);
        add(btn);
        add(lb);
        add(lb1);
        add(tf1);
        add(lb2);
        add(tf2);
        add(lb3);
        add(tf3);
        add(lb4);
        add(tf4);
        //Set TextField Editable False
        tf1.setEditable(false);
        tf2.setEditable(false);
        tf3.setEditable(false);
        tf4.setEditable(false);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //Create DataBase Coonection and Fetching Records
        try {
            String str = tf5.getText();
            String url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=" + "C:\\users\\ppreeti\\employee.accdb";
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "", "");
            //Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@mcndesktop07:1521", "sandeep", "welcome");
            PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("select * from emp where uname=?");
            st.setString(1, str);
            //Excuting Query
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                String s = rs.getString(1);
                String s1 = rs.getString(2);
                String s2 = rs.getString(3);
                String s3 = rs.getString(4);
                //Sets Records in TextFields.
                tf1.setText(s);
                tf2.setText(s1);
                tf3.setText(s2);
                tf4.setText(s3);
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name not Found");
            }
            //Create Exception Handler
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
//Running Constructor

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new SwingSearchApp();
    }
}
```

The structure of my table in Access database contains the following fields:-
`uname`, `umail`, `upass`, `upcountry`.

Comment: You are not passing the expected parameters to SQL. It expects 2 parameters. Please debug.

Comment: how should I correct that through my code ?

Comment: Please check you have any spelling mismatch with column name. You shouldn't use any special characters in the column name. If you have, surround the column name with square brackets

Comment: I haven't used any special character in my column name !!

Comment: Do you provide the username and password to establish the connection?

Comment: nopes..so I've left blank in my code !

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.sql.SQLException: \[Microsoft\]\[ODBC Microsoft Access Driver\] Too few parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346306/java-sql-sqlexception-microsoftodbc-microsoft-access-driver-too-few-paramet)

Comment: this might help as well
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216425

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if `uname` doesn't exist in your table. Check the spelling/case.

Reference: [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216425)

**Update:**

Try to modify your code a little to be able to just run a simple query and get a result set. This will then allow you to query for the column names as your driver sees them:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM emp");
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
String firstColumnName = rsmd.getColumnName(1);
// etc..
```

That will tell you for sure.

Comment: uname is the name of my table ! I've cross-checked it. So, I'm 100% sure that this isn't the root of error.

Comment: I somehow have a strong notion that the error lies due to syntax rules of Access Database..but not sure where lies the error. The ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(); statement never seems to execute

Comment: @user3608233 re: "uname is the name of my table !" - If so, then it's no wonder that your code doesn't work. It will only work if your table is named [emp].