# Getting the sql exception that says: Too few parameters. Expected 1

Tags: java, database, ms-access, jdbc, odbc

**java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1** This is a small piece of my s**erver-client** program which retrieves data from an **access database**. I am getting the Exception mentioned before and do not know how to resolve it. I have tried putting the column names into square brackets and a few other suggestions that i could find from similar questions but with no luck. Does anyone know what i have done wrong?And i believe the mistake is within the "query" String but again, do not know what to do to fix it.

```
class Protocol {

public static String processInput(String input) {
    System.out.println("Test");
    String choice = "";
    String index = input.substring(0, input.indexOf("|"));
    switch (index) {
        case "1":
             try {
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Project");
                Statement state = connect.createStatement();
                String search = input.substring(input.indexOf("|") + 1, input.length());
                String query = "SELECT Movies.[movie_name], Genre.[genre_name] " + "FROM Movies, Genre " 
                               + "WHERE Movies.[genre_id] = Genre.[genre_id] " + "AND Movies.[movie_name] = '"
                                + search + "'";
                ResultSet results = state.executeQuery(query);
                while (results.next()) {
                    choice = choice + results.getString(1) + "|" + results.getString(2) + "|";
                }
                if (choice.equals("")) {
                    choice = "0";
                }
            } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e,"Error", 0);
            } break;
```

Comment: Did you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23539180/java-sql-sqlexception-microsoftodbc-microsoft-access-driver-too-few-paramet

Comment: the columns do exist, ive just cross-checked because my tables are Movies(which has the column [movie_name]) and Genre(which has the column [genre_name]) them and will check link now thanks

Comment: still no luck i've checked the column names and they're already in brackets so..

Comment: Could you please put a System.out.println(query) after String query and verify if there is something wrong

Comment: sorry for late reply, it printed the query

Comment: Create a new query object in access and copy/paste the SQL from your program. When you try to run that in Access you may get some more useful information.

Comment: Omw there was a space in my genre_name column.. thanks so much for help though guys i feel like such a nob